# Force Font Choice in Beamer Document

Tags: beamer, fonts, fontspec

I'm trying to set the font for a single part of my presentation (actually a single wordmark throughout), but as far as I can tell I'm not able to override the beamer defaults easily.

Here's an MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

This is the default font.

{\setmainfont{[Poppins-Medium.ttf]}%
This is a different font.
}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

This just results in both being in default font.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to load the fonttheme `professionalfonts` and set the sans font, as this is what `beamer` is using as default.

`\setmainfont` is an alias for `\setromanfont`, which is maybe a bit misleading.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

This is the default font.

{\setsansfont{Poppins-Medium.ttf}%
This is a different font.
}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This shouldn't be the accepted answer as `\setsansfont` should not be used to temporarily change the font. So Herbert's answer which is using `\newfontface` is better. And although using the `professionalfonts` theme is the first thing one should do if font related problems occur with beamer, it is not needed in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The optional argument `professionalfonts` is a bit misleading. It doesn't mean that Beamer will use professional fonts, whatever this may be. A better name would be `userfonts`. With enabling `professionalfonts` or loading the font theme, Beamer does nothing with font definition, it leaves all to the user.

```
\documentclass[professionalfonts]{beamer}
\usepackage{fontspec}% Latin Modern will be the default
\newfontface\DejaVu{DejaVu Sans}% I don't have the Poppins font
%\setmainfont{DejaVu Sans}%  for the whole document    
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
This is the default font.

\DejaVu
This is the DejaVu font.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```